# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 and linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c

I run the following code from APUE

```
#include "apue.h" 
#include <sys/wait.h>

void pr_exit(int status)
{
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
        printf("normal termination, exit status = %d\n", 
            WEXITSTATUS(status));
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
        printf("abnormal termination, signal number = %d%s\n", 
            WTERMSIG(status), 
#ifdef WCOREDUMP 
            WCOREDUMP(status) ? " (core file generated)" : "");
#else 
        "");
#endif 
    else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) 
        printf("child stopped, signal number = %d\n", 
            WSTOPSIG(status));
}
```

but get error:

```
$ cc my_wait.c 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I checked multiple times and ensure there no difference with the book's instruction ..

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: It seems you need to get a beginners book or two about C and read from the very start.

Comment: The error message says "there is no function `main()`", and the source code you show has no function `main()`, so there's minimal surprise that there's an error message.  Where did you think `main()` was going to come from?

Comment: ty, could you please transmit the comment to answer. @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348398/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-and-linker-command-failed-with-exit-co?noredirect=1#comment93575377_53348398) into an answer, as requested.*</sup>

The error message says "there is no function `main()`", and the source code you show has no function `main()`, so there's minimal surprise that there's that error message.

Where did you think `main()` was going to come from?

When you build a program, there needs to be a `main()` from somewhere, and the standard C library does not provide an implementation.  (If you work with Flex or Lex, or Bison or Yacc, you may find minimal `main()` programs in their libraries, but these are an exception, not the rule.)